# ajax JSONP alway return Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request to a remote api.

This is the response I receive when i'm just browsing to the URL:

```
{ 
  "organizations":[],
  "displayName":"Asaf Nevo",
  "roles":[
            {
              "name":"provider",
              "id":"106"
            }
           ],
  "app_id":"app_id",
  "email":"email",
  "id":"id"
}
```

Now the api is in a different ORIGIN so I needed to use JSONP in my call:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: KeyrockConfig.defaultInstanceUrl + uri,
        type: method,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: params,
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            callback(result, status, xhr);
        },
        //TODO consider having a different callback for error
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            callback(error, status, xhr);
        }
    }
);
```

But I'm keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

I tried to do:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: KeyrockConfig.defaultInstanceUrl + uri,
        type: method,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp:false,
        jsonpCallback: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },

        data: params,
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            callback(result, status, xhr);
        },
        //TODO consider having a different callback for error
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            callback(error, status, xhr);
        }
    }
);
```

But the alert was never called. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to format your json to a string or an array. to test this, try an alert like this `alert(JSON.stringify(your_json_obj));`